# new laptop can only connect to wifi when it is unsecured

Tags: wireless-networking

I got a new Dell Inspirion 14z the other day and it has been on and off connecting to my wifi.  Tonight specifically I have had a total connection failure and it only seems to be able to connect and remain stable for a prolonged period when I set the router to unsecured (not wep or wpa) I know this connection works because I have 4 other laptops some smartphones, and a wii, all running on it fine. What could cause this?

The router is a netgear wireless-n 150 ([seen here](http://www.officemax.com/technology/networking-equipment/routers/product-prod3770199?cm_mmc=Googlepla-_-Technology-_-Networking%20Equipment-_-Routers&ci_src=17588969&ci_sku=23220925&gclid=CObDrb23o60CFQjd4AodV3fkmg))

I have it set to WPA-PSK [TKIP] + WPA2-PSK [AES] currently and have tried changing that to both WPA-PSK [TKIP], and WPA2-PSK [AES] btut nothing seems to work unless I just turn security off all together. sometimes just simply unplugging the router and waiting 30 seconds resolves the issue but not tonight.

Help?

Comment: Try updating the wireless network drivers. You can also try removing the Dell preloaded software for WLAN management and revert to the other evil; Windows Wireless Network Management.

Comment: try updating the drivers and see if that helps. Also are you using the dell wireless tool, or windows config?

Comment: Can you describe the problem in more detail? What exactly goes wrong? What messages do you see? Does it stay "unstable" until you do something to fix it? Or does it fix itself?

Comment: I have "intel my wifi technology" installed. Should I uninstall and reinstall that?